# Summation of the Bergman kernel at two distinct points is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}.$ Let $K(z,w)$ denotes the Bergman kernel of $\Omega.$ Let $w_1,\,w_2$ be two distinct points in $\Omega.$ I'm looking for a domain $\Omega$ bounded and simply connected such that $K(z,w_1)+K(z,w_2)=1$

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a *quadrature domain* with *two nodes*. Such a domain is known as a Neumann oval, and is pictured on page 4 of [Topology of quadrature domains](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0487) by Lee and Makarov. It is the image of an ellipse with center at $0$ under the inversion $z \mapsto 1/z$. Recommended reading:

- [The Bergman kernel and quadrature domains in the plane](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403371) by Bell.
- [What is a quadrature domain?](http://www.math.kth.se/~gbjorn/qd.pdf) by Gusraffson and Shapiro.
- [Selected topics on quadrature domains](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~mputinar/PhysicaD.pdf) by Gustaffson and Putinar.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Actually I was reading about Quadrature domains, particularly classical quadrature domains.